# nuxt Vue Components, computed value is "undefined"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, computed-properties

I am trying to get data through NUXT Api.
also want to return it to the computed property.
I'm sure I missed some stupid mistake or something simple.

I appreciate help.

```
async asyncData ({ app, params }) {
    let listdata = []
    try {
      const Id = params.someid
      const { data } = await app.$axios.get(`/api/some/path/me/${Id}`)
      listdata = data
      return {
        listdata
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return (e)
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
```

`computed` here.

```
  computed: {
    returnlist () {
      const list = this.listdata
      return list
    }
  },
```

and result `undefined`
[image: undefined]

`listdata` console.log here

```
{data: Array(4), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: '/api/some/path/me/Obj_id', method: 'get', headers: {…}, baseURL: '/', transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: Array(4)
0: {partiant: Array(2), _id: 'Obj_id', sender: 'Obj_id', …}
1: {partiant: Array(2), _id: 'Obj_id', sender: 'Obj_id', …}
2: {partiant: Array(2), _id: 'Obj_id', sender: 'Obj_id', …}
3: {partiant: Array(2), _id: 'Obj_id', sender: 'Obj_id', …}
length: 4
...

status: 200
statusText: "OK"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Declare listdata in data(), and use it as this.listdata in your async function.

Comment: It's very good.
And I got this value.
display
listdata:function Object()

value

{
"_custom": {
"type": "function",
"display": "<span style=\"opacity:.5;\">function</span> Object()",
"tooltip": "<pre>function Object() { [native code] }</pre>",
"_reviveId": 6
}
}


How do I handle the code functionObject() {[native code]}?

Comment: Please update your question rather than asking something (especially with code) in comments.

Comment: @J.Titus nope, you're not supposed to declare it in `data`, `asyncData` will merge it to `data` itself. Please follow the guidelines regarding this hook: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#async-data

Comment: Didn't realize that wasn't a method op was declaring. My bad.